# Non-linear regression with parameter constraints based on other parameters

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, non-linear-regression

I am trying to fit a non-linear regression (two phase exponential decay) of the form

SpanFast=(Y0-Plateau) * PercentFast * .01

SpanSlow=(Y0-Plateau) * (100-PercentFast) * .01

Y=Plateau + SpanFast * exp(-KFast * X) + SpanSlow * exp(-KSlow * X)

When I do the calculations in python using scipy.optimize.curve_fit I get a different result than graphpad prism. And I think it is because I don't have the constraints: KFast>KSlow>0. But how is this done in python? How can you constraint a parameter based on another parameter KFast>KSlow.

```
import scipy.optimize as op
def phaseDecay(x, Y0, Plateau, PercentFast, KFast, KSlow):
    """
    Exponential two phase decay

    Parameters:
    -----------
    """
    SpanFast = (Y0-Plateau)*PercentFast*0.01
    SpanSlow = (Y0-Plateau)*(100-PercentFast)*0.01
    Y = Plateau+SpanFast*np.exp(-KFast*x)+SpanSlow*np.exp(-KSlow*x)
    return Y

popt, pcov = op.curve_fit(
    phaseDecay, 
    df["x"], 
    df["y"],
)
```

gives:

```
PARAMETERS:
Y0 100.000000000216
Plateau 69.27241846348228
PercentFast 1.0
KFast 1.0
KSlow 1.0
```

yet prism gives

```
     Y0 100.0
     Plateau    63.58
     PercentFast    72.23
     KFast  0.001626
     KSlow  0.0001125
```

Data:

```
0       0  100.000000
1    1320   75.323025
2    4500   71.880123
3    7800   70.038842
4   18660   66.408841
5       0  100.000000
6    1500   73.127293
7    4140   68.821849
8    7320   65.775435
9   18540   62.800071
10      0  100.000000
11   1740   75.241496
12   3960   68.779365
13   7440   67.843209
14  18360   65.229471
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with SciPy if you convert your objective function into a sum of squared differences and then use a method that supports linear inequalities, like SLSQP.

I did it this way:

```
import scipy.optimize as op
import numpy as np


def phaseDecay(x, xdata, ydata):
    """
    Exponential two phase decay

    Parameters:
    -----------
    """
    
    Y0, Plateau, PercentFast, KFast, KSlow = x
    
    SpanFast = (Y0-Plateau)*PercentFast*0.01
    SpanSlow = (Y0-Plateau)*(100-PercentFast)*0.01
    Y = Plateau+SpanFast*np.exp(-KFast*xdata)+SpanSlow*np.exp(-KSlow*xdata)
    return np.sum((Y - ydata)**2.0)

def constraints(x):

    return x[-2] - x[-1]

    
data = np.loadtxt('data_phase_decay.txt')
X0, Y0 = data[:, 1:].T

lb = np.zeros((5, )) + 1e-5
ub = np.array([100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 0.01, 0.01])
x0 = (ub + lb)/2.0
bounds = zip(lb, ub)
    
# Tell SLSQP that KSlow < KFast
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraints})

res = op.minimize(phaseDecay, x0, method='SLSQP', constraints=cons,
                  args=(X0, Y0))
print(res)
```

and I get the following:

```
fun    : 30.45577816182897
jac    : array([-2.44140625e-04,   1.53160095e-03,  -2.43663788e-04,
                0.00000000e+00,  -2.11278069e+01,   0.00000000e+00])
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nfev   : 247
nit    : 27
njev   : 27
status : 0
success: True
x      : array([9.99999153e+01,   6.46585138e+01,   6.27658587e+01,
                2.33870123e-02,   2.02987854e-04])
                
Y0          = 99.999915
Plateau     = 64.658514
PercentFast = 62.765859
KFast       = 0.023387
KSlow       = 0.000203
```